# How to POST JSON data in Azure DevOps with PHP after the click of a button, I have a working code in PowerShell

Tags: php, html, forms, powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to post a JSON data in Azure DevOps. I have written a same code in PowerShell and it's working fine. Here is the PowerShell Code.

```
$organization = "DevOpsOrg"
$project = "Worldhealthgroup"
$url_base = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/"
$url_endpoint = "_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=6.0-preview.2"
$url = $url_base + $url_endpoint

$pat = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$token =[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))

$JSON = @'
{
    "description": "TestVariableGroup",
    "name": "TestVariableGroup",
    "providerData": null,
    "type": "Vsts",
    "variables": {"applicationID": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-75cf76fc40c8"
    },
    "ResourceGroupName": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "TestRG1"
    },
    "VirtualMachineName": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "TestVM1"
    },
    "imagesize": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "Standard_B2ms"
    },
    "location": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "eastus"
    },
    "imageVnet": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "LocalVnet"
    },
    "imageSubnet": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "Subnet1"
    },
    "imagestorageRg": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "Img_rg"
    }}, 
    "variableGroupProjectReferences": [{
        "description": "TestVariableGroup",
        "name": "TestVariableGroup",
        "projectReference": {
            "id": "projectId",
            "name": "Worldhealthgroup"
        }
    }]
}
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -ContentType application/json -body $JSON
```

I have tried the following code in PHP but I am getting error.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit']))
{
$organization = "DevOpsOrg"
$project = "Worldhealthgroup"
$url_base = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/"
$url_endpoint = "_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=6.0-preview.2"
$url = $url_base.$url_endpoint;
$pattoken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  
$ci = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
  curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
  curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
  curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
  curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setpot($ci, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
  curl_setpot($ci, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{
    "description": "TestVariableGroup",
    "name": "TestVariableGroup",
    "providerData": null,
    "type": "Vsts",
    "variables": {"applicationID": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-75cf76fc40c8"
    },
    "ResourceGroupName": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "TestRG1"
    },
    "VirtualMachineName": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "TestVM1"
    },
    "imagesize": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "Standard_B2ms"
    },
    "location": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "eastus"
    },
    "imageVnet": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "LocalVnet"
    },
    "imageSubnet": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "Subnet1"
    },
    "imagestorageRg": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "Img_rg"
    }}, 
    "variableGroupProjectReferences": [{
        "description": "TestVariableGroup",
        "name": "TestVariableGroup",
        "projectReference": {
            "id": "projectId",
            "name": "Worldhealthgroup"
        }
    }]

}'
);
  curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "content-type: application/json",
    "content-length: 0",
    "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode(":".$pattoken)   // This is the best way to convert the best 64 string in PHP
    )
  ); 
}
?>

<form action="" method="post"  name ="formimagecatalog" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">  
    <div class="box-footer">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="btnsubmit">Submit</button>
          </div>
    </form>
```

I am getting Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_setpot() in C:\xampp\htdocs\restapi2\devopspost.php.

Can anyone please help here.

Comment: Put the path of your PHP file into the action prop of your form, or put the php inside the same file as your form and declare <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> in the action prop instead. If you don't want to perform a redirect or a page refresh, remember to perform an e.preventDefault() on the form logic.

Comment: I am actually looking to convert the powershell code into PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I able to resolve the issue by the below code.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://dev.azure.com/xxxxx/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=6.0-preview.2',
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization)
  ),
);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
  } else {
    echo $response;
  }
}
?>
```